# Use a parameter to select a table in a raw SQL Alchemy query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm not using the ORM and I am looking to do this:

```
table = 'foo'
engine.execute('SELECT * from %s', (table))
```

The problem is that turns into:

```
SELECT * FROM 'foo'
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM foo
```

I can't find the documentation on the available % parameters. I tried %b but it is not supported.

Without using the ORM, what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: In general, parameters can only be used where expressions are allowed. You can't use them for table or column names.

Comment: Just do ordinary string formatting. You'll need to do your own sanitization, to make sure that the table is allowed.

Comment: It should be very rare that you need to allow table names to come from an untrusted source.

Comment: What about for numbers? Is there any way to drop the quotes so that I can do `('x > %s', number)` and it will compute?

Comment: MySQL will automatically convert the string to a number before doing the comparison.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar